# UnlockFocus called too many times console message when showing a popover by storybard segue

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a 'Bevel' style button in OSX app. When pressing it, it opens a popover by a segue. No coding yet, just storyboarding. I have not written any lines of code according to it yet, no code behind.

When pressing the button first time the following message appears in XCode console:
unlockFocus called too many times. Called on

The popover itself appears in the right way.

Later clicking the button I don't get this message.

What can be the problem? Very strange.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
```

before the popup opens.